# My organs spontaneously combust - who/what am i?

Tags: riddle

My tears crash but never fall
Various dislikes circle
Past thoughts tinged with sadness
My organs spontaneously combust

Who or what am I?

Comment: I haven't solved it but I did end up at an article about Spontaneous Human Combustion...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> Bullet for My Valentine?

Each line is a

> Song title

*My tears crash but never fall*

> Tears don't fall

*Various dislikes circle*

> All these things I hate (revolve around me)

*Past thoughts tinged with sadness*

> Bittersweet memories

*My organs spontaneously combust*

> Hearts burst into fire

Answer (score 5):

You could be

> The Atlantic Ocean

My tears crash but never fall

> Waves could be considered to be the ocean's tears, and they crash but do not fall.

Various dislikes circle

> A reference to large gyres and/or eddies in the ocean.

Past thoughts tinged with sadness

> Oceans are often associated with melancholy.

My organs spontaneously combust

> The mid-Atlantic ridge is a hotbed of volcanic activity.